# Runtime Exception Booted CiviCRM, but failed to find 'api/class.api.php'

Tags: civireport, custom-reports, civix

I created an extension module with `civix` then cd'd to the module directory and tried to create a custom report based on a copy of an existing report. I used the following command:

```
$ civix generate:report --copy CRM_Report_Form_Case_Summary DemandCaseReport CiviCase
```

This generates an error message that I haven't yet been able to fix.

```
Initialize report CRM_Case_Form_Report_DemandCaseReport


[RuntimeException]                                      
Booted CiviCRM, but failed to find 'api/class.api.php'  


generate:report [--webPath [WEBPATH]] [--copy [COPY]] [--] <<ClassName>> <<CiviComponent>>
```

I'm using civix version v16.03.2-3-geeff5c0. It's a WordPress installation.

I can see that a file with that name resides in `/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/class.api.php`

Is there an environment variable that I should be setting or something else that I'm overlooking?

Grateful for any tips, thanks.

Comment: which version of civicrm and wordpress are you using ?

Comment: WP 4.3 civicrm 4.5.8

Comment: I did manage to create same report against Civi 4.6.10 and everything went alright with just one warning - is their anyway you can test the same against 4.6.10

Comment: I upgraded to 4.6.20 but I'm afraid I got exactly the same error. :(
BTW I'm using WP 4.5.3, not 4.3. Sorry about that.

Comment: It appears that civix is ignoring or overwriting my modifications of the `include_path`. I added the full path name  `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxx/civcrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm` (where `api` resides) to `include_path` in the `php.ini` (checked I got the right one with `php --ini`).  That didn't work.

But I got it to work by soft linking the api directory into the extension directory (changed directory to the extension directory and did the following command:

`$ ln -s /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxx/civcrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `civix` is ignoring or overwriting additions to or modifications of the `include_path`. I added the full path name `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxx/civcrm/‌​wp-content/plug‌​ins/civicrm/‌​civicrm` (where `api` resides) to `include_path` in the `php.ini` (checked I got the right one with `php --ini`). That didn't work.

But I got it to work by soft linking the `api` directory into the new extension directory, i.e. changed directory to the extension directory and did the following command: `$ ln -s /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxx/civcrm/‌​wp-content/plug‌​ins/civicrm/‌​civicrm/api .`

It's not an ideal solution but it enabled meet move forward.